# Command line equivalent of "$preview_mode = 1"?

Tags: latexmk

I'm setting up variants of running the latexmk command, and need some help writing a command line that will be used whenever I do not want to use the `.latexmkrc` file (i.e., -norc).  On Mac, it is sometimes necessary to use `$preview_mode = 1` when not running continuous preview in order to launch a previewer.  Is there a command line equivalent for `$preview_mode = 1`?

Comment: Sorry, it's late and I've been at this all day, it looks like it is just plain old "-pv".

Comment: Yes, cf. the bottom of p. 24 of the [latexmk documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/support/latexmk/latexmk.pdf). Feel free to self-answer your question.

Comment: @doncherry Could you make that an answer?

Comment: Sorry for leaving the question open so long -- I've added the answer and checked it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-pv` is the command line equivalent for the `.latexmkrc` form of `$preview_mode = 1`.